# How send a trap from Linux Command line using a MIB file

Tags: linux, snmp

I want to use this MIB file.

https://www-304.ibm.com/webapp/set2/sas/f/hmc/mib.html

Need to use Linux command line command snmptrap to send trap to some host. The trap data cpsSystemSendTrap is a string.

What could be the command format for version 1 and version 2 trap?

Also, are MIBs specific for snmp versions?

Answer (score 0):

You can download mib file and specify it for `snmptrap` command to use. For version 1 snmp trap command would

```
snmptrap -m ./ibmConvergedPowerSystems.mib  -v 1 -c public 127.0.0.1 IBM-CPS-MIB::problemTrap 127.0.0.1 6 17 '' cpsSystemSendTrap s "textual description"
```

snmp v2 trap:

```
snmptrap -m ./ibmConvergedPowerSystems.mib -v 2c -c public 127.0.0.1 '' IBM-CPS-MIB::problemTrap cpsSystemSendTrap s "some other text"
```